# How to change the color of status bar when android:theme is used in manifest file?

Tags: android

I'm using `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` in my Android manifest file for my activity. But the color of the status bar is being set to Black. How do I change it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case attaching your manifest file would let folks see if there are any settings that would cause that, or not. If not they could ask about sections of your code that might be causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a style to styles.xml and set `colorPrimaryDark` to be whatever colour you want your status bar to be

like this...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and in your manifest reference it with

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```